# Simple C# (ASP.Net website) using entityspaces sample

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, entityspaces

Are there anyone in here who ever using entityspaces for database generation in ASP.Net website (c# language)? I need a simple sample to connecting between the database (sql server engine) to the website form using entityspaces component. Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

The [EntitySpaces website](http://www.entityspaces.net) has documentation, [forums](http://www.entityspaces.net/www.entityspaces.net/Portal/Support/Forums.aspx.html), a walk-through video and even a getting started pdf.  These seem to be the easiest places to find samples and examples.

Hopefully, you get what you need before the website is [shut down for good](http://www.entityspaces.net/www.entityspaces.net/blog/2012/09/21/EntitySpaces%20To%20Shutdown%20Move%20To%20Open%20Source.aspx.html).

Comment: shut down for good? where did it go (I can't click on the link as it is down now)

Comment: Ah actually remember reading that now, thanks. The on-line documentation was by no means perfect but there was a lot there, so annoying this is no longer accessible anywhere =(